# Set Up Google Maven Dependencies For Use Offline

Tags: android-studio, gradle, offline, maven-dependency

I'm just trying to set up the Google Maven dependencies that I downloaded from:

https://d.android.com/r/studio-offline/downloads

I followed the "README" instructions and then tried to verify everything was working by commenting out jcenter() and google() from my project's "build.gradle".

[When I try to run my project, this is the error I get:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XM8YL.png)

Error: Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2.

Error: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.30.

[README](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KA0Tz.png)